# What's the best practice to use OceanBase in cloud environment

Tags: database, cloud, distributed-database, cloud-native

What's the best practice to use OceanBase in cloud environment

1. Cloud Provider Compatibility
2. Configuration and Tuning
3. High Availability and Disaster Recovery
4. Monitoring and Maintenance
5. Cost Optimization

reading the documents from the official website, there's so many tools to operate OceanBase, but not sure which one to use
https://en.oceanbase.com/docs/oceanbase-database